# Why would application settings not work in an Outlook Add-in or other environment

Tags: c#, visual-studio, outlook-addin

The [Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4s6c3a0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for application settings states that:

> You cannot use application settings in an unmanaged application that hosts the .NET Framework. Settings will not work in such environments as Visual Studio add-ins, C++ for Microsoft Office, control hosting in Internet Explorer, or Microsoft Outlook add-ins and projects.

I created a string in application settings and accessed it from the code, in a Microsoft Outlook Add-in. It seemed to work fine.

In what situations would it not work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of unanswered question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948936/applicationsettings-in-net-from-unmanaged-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application settings rely on the presence of a ".config" file to read from. Precisely this would be the ".exe.config" for exe hosts or "web.config" for IIS apps. Outlook, IExplore etc... don't come with *your* config file. Have you tried changing the value? Settings created with VS have hardcoded defaults and you might be tricked into thinking that it works...

EDIT: The original post stands, because that is how the basic .NET mechanism for configuration files works. However, a host application that runs the .NET Framework has to create an "Application Domain" for it (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain(v=vs.110).aspx )
As part of the creation information for that AppDomain object, the host can specify the path to a configuration file to use (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomainsetup.configurationfile(v=vs.110).aspx ). The OS-loader (for EXEs) creates an AppDomain with the ".config" added to the EXE's path as a config file. It seems that (at least some versions of Outlook/.NET) will use the plugin DLL's path with the ".config" addon. This is hard to replicate for me right now but plausible. I remember with an Outlook 2007/.NET 2 addin, it didn't work.

Comment: Actually, it did publish a ".dll.config" that works for the outlook add-in. Is this different than what I am referring to?

Comment: The ".dll.config" is just a way for visual studio to keep track of the settings that your DLL requires. But to use them, you would need to copy them into the the corresponding ".exe.config"

Comment: Changing the application settings in the ".dll.config" for a published add-in changed the behavior of the add-in though.

Comment: Interesting... I'll look into that on the weekend. Last time I checked, just adding a ".dll.config" didn't have any effect on the runtime. Or did you change the settings in the VS solution before deploying or debugging? Also: what version of outlook/vs are you using?

Comment: I published and deployed to a different computer than the dev environment, then modified the ".dll.config" file there. I'm using VS 2010, Outlook 2010, Office Assembly Version 14, .NET Framework 4. The ".dll.config" doesn't appear to exist on the computer I'm debugging on, just the one I deployed to.

Comment: @Justin I validated some details and updated the answer. Right now my OL2010/VS2010 VM sadly is in a coma but it seems version dependant.